# Knockout - changing another viewmodel value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a header in Master Layout, and content in every page. The master layout has its own view model, and each of the content in every page have its own model as well.

The problem I am having is when I am trying to update the user profile, the changes is not reflected in the header as the two view model is separated. How can I make the header to reflect the instance immediately when I update the profile?

```js
// Header View Model (serve from Master Layout)
function HeaderViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.headerusername = ko.observable();
  self.headerprofileImage = ko.observable(); // base 64 image
}
ko.applyBindings(new HeaderViewModel(), document.getElementById('header');

// Profile View Model (profile.html)
function ProfileViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.username = ko.observable();
  self.profileImage = ko.observable(); // base 64 image
}
ko.applyBindings(new ProfileViewModel(), document.getElementById('profile');
```

```html
<!-- Header (serve from master layout) -->
<header id="header">
  <span data-bind="text:headerusername"></span>
  <img data-bind="attr: {src:headerprofileImage }">
</header>


<!-- Update profile (profile.html) -->
<form id="profile>
<input type="text" data-bind="value:username">
<input type="file" data-bind="value:profileImage">
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: [ko.postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) is precisely developed for these kind of scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ko.contextFor(element)` to access the [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) of the header from within a method of your profile view model using code like:

```
var headerContext = ko.contextFor(document.getElementById('header'));
headerContext.$data.headerusername(self.username());
headerContext.$data.headerprofileImage(self.profileImage());
```

Comment: can u explain why $data is necessary in this case?

Comment: `$data` is simply the property where the view model data is available in the binding context. See the "binding context" link in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually organize each `viewModel` in its own module using `require.js`.

Then I would define a singleton component module (a module that always returns an instance of the same class) called `ProfileService` to act as the shared profile data.

Both `HeaderViewModel` and `ProfileViewModel` would require `ProfileService`.

`ProfileService` could contain the methods to interface with the API and could expose `username` and `profileImage` observables.

`HeaderViewModel` and `ProfileViewModel` would import the shared observables from `ProfileService`:

File `ProfileService`:

```
define(function() {
    function ProfileService() {
        var self = this;
        self.username = ko.observable();
        self.profileImage = ko.observable();

        // logic to retrieve/update data
    }
    return new ProfileService();
});
```

File `ProfileViewModel`:

```
define(['path/to/ProfileService', 'path/to/knockout.js'], function(ProfileService, ko) {
    function ProfileViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.username = ProfileService.username;
        self.profileImage = ProfileService.profileImage;
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new ProfileViewModel(), document.getElementById('profile');
});
```

[EDIT]

As suggested in the comments by @Kal_Torak, you could implement something similar without `require.js`, just sharing data in the global namespace. Something like:

```
window.ProfileService = {
    username: ko.observable(),
    profileImage: ko.observable()
}
```

But if you don't know `require.js` yet, I would suggest that you take the time to give it a try.

Comment: I was just about to answer along this vein.  I would add, if the OP doesn't wish to go with Requirejs, another option would be to store the singleton data globally. e.g. window.myNamespace.sharedData = {user:ko.observable() }

Comment: @Andrea Cassaccia thanks for the reply. But actually I am trying to solve the bug assigned. Meaning that the project code itself already well established and it is unpractical to restructure it.